# what's this python syntax dict(name=name)?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

I've encounter this syntax in [the srapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data).

```
>>> abc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> dict(abc=abc)
{'abc': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

There doesn't seem to have this syntax mentioned in [the python dict documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict). What is this syntax called?

Comment: It's just a function call with single keyword argument. `dict(abc=1)` may be an easier way to comprehend what's happening here.

Comment: `dict(a=1)` is equal to `{'a': 1}`

Comment: I want to know why abc=abc expands in dict like having 'abc' as key and the list as value, and is there's specific syntax name for this?

Comment: @user14042 keyword arguments are interpreted literally, they are not names to be resolved.

Comment: It's work like this: `def a(**kwargs): print(kwargs)`

Comment: thanks guys, learning about keyword argument is nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument).

It is roughly the same as:

```
def make_dict(**kwargs):
    return kwargs
```

In your case,

```
abc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict(abc=abc)
```

means:

```
dict(abc=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

which is the same as:

```
{'abc': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special, `dict()` can take keyword arguments as well as positional arguments. You can read the [docs on `dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

So in your code snippet `dict()` just take single keyword argument.